# Why there isn't a simpler way to stop an activity from another?

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

I know there are many topics about this, and I understand (or at least I think I do) the Activity lifecycle. I know the Activity itself should handle its lifecycle, including the process of stopping the Activity.

But, in some cases, this is just not practical, for example, if you have a controller, to manage your interface, and maybe receiving I/O results.

So, wouldn't be nice just to send some Intent with an action like a `ACTION_STOP_REQUEST`, and let the Activity handle it?

Comment: From the little info you give it sounds like you should be looking at using a Service.

Comment: @rreeverb I wasn't asking about an specific case, but I gave an example, but still i would have the same question of the controller was a Service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > So, wouldn't be nice just to send some Intent with an action like a *WHATEVER*, and let the Activity handle it?

AFAIK, that's what [`BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)s are for.

Comment: Well, but to have a BroadcastReceiver doing that, you need to keep an instance of every Activity you want to "control". It reduces the possibilities.

Comment: No, I mean, you declare the BroadcastReceiver inside the activity. And kill it from there.

Comment: that might be the answer to mi, according to the replies and comments, silly question. I will try. Never thought of that.

Answer (score 2):

As Cristian suggested, use `BroadcastReceiver`

You could include private `BroadcastReceiver`s in each Activity that you would want to respond to the `ACTION_STOP_REQUEST` and have them call `finish()` in `onReceive()`